# R: lubridate's dst() not working as expected

Tags: r, timezone, dst, lubridate

I suspect I am doing something very silly, but I can't get the `dst` function in `lubridate` to work as expected.

```
library(lubridate)

x <- c("2016-01-01", "2016-06-01")

dst(x) # Returns c(FALSE, TRUE)
dst(as.Date(x)) # Returns c(FALSE, FALSE)
```

The result I expect in both cases is `c(FALSE, TRUE)`. However, I only get the expected result if I pass `dst` a character vector and not with a `Date` object. I'm using OS X, my current timezone is PST (`America/Los_Angeles`).

Comment: hi pbaylis, can you tell us what result you expect?

Comment: `dst(x)` returns `c(FALSE,FALSE)` for me. What timezone are you in? `dst(x)` calls `as.POSIXlt(x)$isdst` which uses the system timezone.

Comment: I expect `c(FALSE, TRUE)` and I'm in PST (edited question accordingly).

Comment: Unfortunately the system time zone for Macs is sometimes `""`, but I'm unable to reproduce on an ElCap box running R 3.3.2 RC. I get `[1] FALSE  TRUE`

Comment: I can replicate with `c(NA, FALSE, TRUE)[as.POSIXlt(x,tz="America/Los_Angeles")$isdst + 2]` and `c(NA, FALSE, TRUE)[as.POSIXlt(as.Date(x),tz="America/Los_Angeles")$isdst + 2]` - as per the code that is in `dst.default`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dst()` calls a piece of code which is essentially:

```
c(NA, FALSE, TRUE)[as.POSIXlt(x)$isdst + 2]
```

`as.POSIXlt` is by default:

```
as.POSIXlt(x=, tz="")
```

...which will take your system timezone by default. So, given your location in L.A., let's look at:

```
as.POSIXlt(x, tz="America/Los_Angeles")
#[1] "2016-01-01 PST" "2016-06-01 PDT"
c(NA, FALSE, TRUE)[as.POSIXlt(x, tz="America/Los_Angeles")$isdst + 2]
#[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Everything is fine. Hooray. Now, let's try with `as.Date(x)`

```
as.POSIXlt(as.Date(x))
#[1] "2016-01-01 UTC" "2016-06-01 UTC"
as.POSIXlt(as.Date(x), tz="America/Los_Angeles")
#[1] "2016-01-01 UTC" "2016-06-01 UTC"
```

Ohhh. So, `as.POSIXlt` does not play nicely with `Date` objects, and always returns `UTC` instead of the local timezone, and seemingly ignores any `tz=` argument. And since `UTC` does not abide by any daylight savings, you will always end up with `FALSE` returned.

Looking at the R source code, this seems to be the case. In https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/datetime.c you can find:

```
# R call:
#> as.POSIXlt.Date
#function (x, ...) 
#.Internal(Date2POSIXlt(x))

# source code:
#SEXP attribute_hidden do_D2POSIXlt(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP env)
#{
#...
setAttrib(ans, s_tzone, mkString("UTC"));
```

...as a hard-coded string.

Comment: Thanks, this is illuminating. This seems like a bug to me, but I'm not sure. The [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html) for `as.POSIXlt` says "Dates without times are treated as being at midnight UTC," so perhaps it's the expected behavior. 

My workaround for now is to use `as.character(as.Date(x))`, but I have a large dataset and the conversion to a character vector is costly.